# Capture specific-sized images with an Ubuntu command-line program

Tags: command-line, ubuntu, video-processing

I am currently working on a project and would like to know if you heard of any command-line tools that lets your webcam take specific-sized images? I found some but none of them works.

In my case, I'd need to capture 1600x1200 pictures.

Comment: Cheese is a good example of what I need to do. However, I need to control it by command-line.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use

```
uvccapture -m -x640 -y480 -oimage.jpg.
```

If your webcam supports 1600x1200, then this method might work. When I try anything more than 640x480, uvccapture prints:

```
format asked unavailable get width 640 height 480
```